# Internal server error in loadrunner script while replay

Tags: ios, api, loadrunner

I've recorded a workflow using proxy recorder for a mobile application which is using API calls in VUGEN(loadrunner 12.55). I am getting internal server error 500 during update (POST) function. Following is the code snippet of script generated by Loadrunner

```
web_submit_data("signin", 
        "Action=http://beautymarksapp.com/api/user/signin", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncodeAtSign=YES", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=email", "Value=user@domain.com", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=password", "Value=BMARKS", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=timezone", "Value=18000", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("update", 
        "URL=http://beautymarksapp.com/api/user/update", 
        "Method=PUT", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t2.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "Body=device_token=c7ff93995d1dea60fea773819b582235b6367c0c7275238a65c2035c2d96fde6&device_type=ios", 
        LAST);
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell from your description. Does the same request work in a tool like Postman?

Comment: I didn't actually tried, will give it a try and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer for 500 are:

- Unhandled Dynamic Item
- No checking for expected results
- No exception handling/branching when unexpected results appear